# Docker tool or feature to define per-project container aliases?

Tags: docker

I would like to use Docker to be more flexible in the dependencies my projects use. For example, project A might want to use PHP 5, and project B use PHP 7.

Obviously (and sticking with this example), I can use `docker run ... php:5 ...` or `docker run ... php:7 ...` to run either version.

But, if you switch between projects a lot and have many tools packed up as containers (not just PHP, but also Node.js, Ruby, Ant, ...) things get out of hand.

*Yes*, I could write a lot of shell scripts as wrappers. So, in project A, have a `bin/php` wrapper script to `docker run ... php:5 ...`, and in project B, make `bin/php` run `... php:7 ...`.

What I don't like about this is the prospect of having to repeat myself over and over again and having lots of similar wrapper scripts in every project.

So, I was hoping to either find an off-the-shelf solution from the Docker ecosystem. Or maybe some Docker feature I have missed so far, like a dot-file for defining container aliases or tags that might help.

Do you know any such tool or how would you approach this?